# React Text Fade in/out on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am using React. When a button is clicked, the text changes. I would like to have the current text fade out and then the new text fade in when the button is clicked.

I tried implementing solutions from other stack overflow posts, but to no avail.

Here is the codepen https://codepen.io/Jamece/pen/PoObBEN

```
const duration =1000;

//creating main React component with state being random numbers that will be an index for the quotes and color array.
class QuoteMachine extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      randomIndexQuote: 0,
      randomIndexColor: 0,
      fadeTransition: null,
      fadeState: "fade-in"
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  //upon click, a random number will be generates and state will be updated

  handleClick() {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        randomIndexQuote: Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length),
        randomIndexColor: Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length),
        fadeTransition: null,
        fadeState: 'fade-in'
      });
    }, duration);

    clearTimeout(this.state.fadeTransition);

    this.setState({
      fadeState: "fade-out",
      fadeTransition: timeout
    });
  }

  render() {
    //variables holding state index
    const quoteOutput = quotes[this.state.randomIndexQuote].quote;
    const authorOutput = quotes[this.state.randomIndexQuote].author;
    //variables for random color styles
    const textStyle = {
      color: colors[this.state.randomIndexColor],
      transition: "all 2s ease"
    };
    const backgroundStyle = {
      backgroundColor: colors[this.state.randomIndexColor],
      transition: "all 2s ease"
    };

    return (
      <div className="container-fluid px-0">
        <div
          className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center main"
          id="quote-box"
          style={backgroundStyle}
        >
          <div className="white-box">
            <div
              className={"fade-wrapper ${this.state.fadeState}"}
              style={{ transitionDuration: "${duration}ms" }}
            >
              <p id="text" style={textStyle} className="text-center">
                "{quoteOutput}"
              </p>
              <p id="author" style={textStyle} className="text-end">
                {authorOutput}
              </p>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
.fade-wrapper {
  transition: opacity ease-in-out;
}
.fade-out {
  opacity: 0;
}
.fade-in {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Pure CSS is stateless (mostly) so you will have a hard time coordinating CSS animation with React state. Ideally try to use a helper library. Otherwise you can try to orchestrate it with setTimeout and match the animation durations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply set the opacity to go from 1 to 0 and back to 1. You have everything ready with the color animation, all you need to do is add the opacity alongside the colors - (https://codepen.io/Brisingr_1/pen/NWwjWLx)

```
this.state = {
  ...,
  opacity: 1
};



const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
  this.setState({
    ...,
    opacity: 1
  });
}, duration);

clearTimeout(this.state.fadeTransition);

this.setState({
  ...,
  opacity: 0,
});




const textStyle = {
  ...,
  opacity: this.state.opacity,
};
```